# Read UDID, Major, Minor of beacon on android devices running on versions prior to 4.3

Tags: android, ibeacon

Is the any way through which i can detect and read UDID, Major, Minor of beacon on android devices running on versions prior to 4.3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Samsung devices with Bluetooth LE this is possible, for other non-jail broken pre-4.3 Android devices it is not.

The problem is you need a Bluetooth LE library to see iBeacons.  Such a library cannot be added to non-jail broken phones because it requires binary driver to the Bluetooth hardware.

Samsung provides this in a proprietary API installed on its phones, but only on newer ones with Bluetooth LE.  For other pre-4.3 phones, I am afraid you are out of luck.